# sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier using strings that should be considered categorical

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am training an `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`.  I start out with a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.  Some of the columns of this data frame are strings that really should be categorical.  For example, 'Color' is one such column and has values such as 'black', 'white', 'red', and so on.  So I convert this column to be of type category like this:

```
data['Color'] = data['Color'].astype('category')
```

This works just fine.  Now I split my data frame using `sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split`, like this:

```
X = data.drop(['OutcomeType'], axis=1)
y = data['OutcomeType']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Now `X_train` has type `numpy.ndarray`.  However, the 'Color' values are no longer categorical, they are back to being strings.

So when I make the following calls:

```
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: Black

What do I need to do to get this working correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure about the details of the algorithm but I think you need dummies rather than category type. With pandas, you can try get_dummies, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html For sklearn there are  similar preprocessing tools http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert your categorical column to an integer, you can use `data.Color.cat.codes`; this uses `data.Color.cat.categories` to perform the mapping (the i'th array element gets mapped to the integer `i`)

Answer (score 2):

As ayhan said, a workaround would be to create dummy features from your 'Color' variable (which are pretty common use with decision trees / RF).

You could use something like this :

```
def feature_to_dummy(df, column, drop=False):
    ''' take a serie from a dataframe,
        convert it to dummy and name it like feature_value
        - df is a dataframe
        - column is the name of the column to be transformed
        - if drop is true, the serie is removed from dataframe'''
    tmp = pd.get_dummies(df[column], prefix=column, prefix_sep='_')
    df = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1, join_axes=[df.index])
    if drop:
        del df[column]
    return df
```

See [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) for `pandas.get_dummies`

**Example**

```
df
Out[1]: 
   color
0    red
1  black
2  green

df_dummy = feature_to_dummy(df, 'color', drop=True)

df_dummy
Out[2]: 
   color_black  color_green  color_red
0            0            0          1
1            1            0          0
2            0            1          0
```